# How to disable specific plugin in mobile version?

Tags: plugins, javascript

I am using wp-cufon plugin , to enable cufon on my site . But I do not want cufon in mobile version . If there is any way to disable that plugin in mobile version or in just disable specific java script ?

Comment: Why do you need different stuff server-side based on the device that the user is using? We are in the responsive design era, that means that the server always performs the same task and send the same information to the user. Then, you can work client-side in different ways based on characteristics of the device (for example, screen resolution), but always client-side. Plus, server-side detection of devices is someting you can not trust.

Answer (score 1):

In wordpress exists [wp_is_mobile()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) function.This may help you.

You must see how is named cufon handle in plugin

```
if(wp_is_mobile()){
    wp_dequeue_script( 'cufon_handle' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but how to disable a specific  plugin in that condition ? Or How to  dequeue a script in that condition , note that , the javascript is attached by a plugin

Comment: I think this [link](http://perishablepress.com/quickly-disable-or-enable-all-wordpress-plugins-via-the-database/) may be useful

Comment: Or you must see how they register script and make deque,`wp_deque_script('plugin_script_name')`,[deque_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script)